# Different results when using more than one thread

Tags: c++, vector, openmp

The following code performs a transpose matrix-vector multiplication where the matrix is sparse and stored in CSR format. Depending on the number of threads the result is different. I think the reason is the concurrent memory access and addition.
Is there a way to use multithreading but keep the result the same as for single threading?

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(m_numthreads)
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.get_rowptr()->size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = matrix.get_rowptr()->operator[](i); j < matrix.get_rowptr()->operator[](i + 1); ++j)
        {
            result[matrix.get_columnindex()->operator[](j)] += matrix.get_value()->operator[](j) * vector1[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nobody can tell, without knowing the types of `result` and `matrix` at least, and whether there's any aliasing of the two.

Comment: result and vector1 are stl double vectors. Matrix is a class which holds the three vectors that are needed to describe a sparse matrix in CSR format.

Comment: A [mcve] would make the question much clearer - could you [edit] so that others can reproduce and diagnose the issue you're seeing?

Comment: BTW, if you're comparing `int` against `std::size_t` like that, it suggests you have nowhere near enough compiler warnings enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The increment operation should indeed be made atomic to make sure two threads are not updating the value at the same time, which would be a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software). This will make the code correct, but since atomic increment is slower than standard increment, it may make the parallel code slower than the serial one overall.
Performance may also be affected by [false-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing): if the vector size is not much greater than the number of threads, it will often happen that two threads attempt to increment values belonging to the same cache line and much time is spent synchronizing the cache between CPUs.

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(m_numthreads)
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.get_rowptr()->size() - 1; ++i)
        for (int j = matrix.get_rowptr()->operator[](i); j < matrix.get_rowptr()->operator[](i + 1); ++j)
        {
            #pragma omp atomic
            result[matrix.get_columnindex()->operator[](j)] += matrix.get_value()->operator[](j) * vector1[i];
        }
```

This being said, for a given element in the result vector, the order in which the various products are added to make that element will not be the same in the serial and parallel cases. Rounding errors will add differently and one should not expect the serial and parallel results to be the same, but rather the difference between these results to be small relative to the precision of the *float* or *double* format.

Comment: You should probably point out that there will be very little (possibly negative) speed increase from parallelisation when the *entire body of the loop* is in an `atomic` block.

Comment: It's probably more efficient to make the elements of `result` be some suitable `std::atomic<>` type instead.  If not, at least bring the computation of lhs and rhs ahead of the `atomic` section, so only the `+=` is affected.

Comment: I have already stated that *since atomic increment is slower than standard increment, it may make the parallel code slower than the serial one*. Then I do not know for sure in which direction the balance between one fast op at a time and several slow ones in parallel will point. This depends on too many factors and there may still be a small performance improvement.

Comment: I have tried the atomic pragma and it worked fine. But as stated, the performance decreased. But I am totaly fine with that. At least I am getting reproducable results.

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, I've had to guess at the context of this code:

```
#include <vector>

class SparseMatrix
{
    std::vector<double> values = { 5, 8, 3, 6, };
    std::vector<std::size_t> rows = { 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, };
    std::vector<std::size_t> cols = { 1, 2, 1, 1, };

public:
    const std::vector<std::size_t> *get_rowptr() const { return &rows; };
    const std::vector<std::size_t> *get_columnindex() const { return &cols; };
    const std::vector<double> *get_value() const { return &values; };
};

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    SparseMatrix matrix;

    std::array<double, 4> result{};
    std::array<double, 4> vector1{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.get_rowptr()->size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = matrix.get_rowptr()->operator[](i); j < matrix.get_rowptr()->operator[](i + 1); ++j)
        {
            result[matrix.get_columnindex()->operator[](j)] += matrix.get_value()->operator[](j) * vector1[i];
        }
    }

    for (auto const& i: result)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

With some suitable variables we can simplify the code so we see what's going on:

```
    auto const& rows = *matrix.get_rowptr();
    auto const& cols = *matrix.get_columnindex();
    auto const& values = *matrix.get_value();

 #pragma omp parallel for
    for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < rows.size() - 1;  ++i)
    {
        for (std::size_t j = rows[i];  j < rows[i+1];  ++j)
        {
            result[cols[j]] += values[j] * vector1[i];
        }
    }
```

Now we can see in the body of the loop that we're assigning to a result entry that other threads may also be writing to.  We need to serialize the access to `result[cols[j]]` so that only one thread at a time is executing the `+=`.  We can do that by marking that operation indivisible, using the OMP `atomic` keyword:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < rows.size() - 1;  ++i)
    {
        for (std::size_t j = rows[i];  j < rows[i+1];  ++j)
        {
            auto& dest = result[cols[j]];
            auto const term = values[j] * vector1[i];
#pragma omp atomic
            dest += term;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Toby. You nailed it. Sorry I was not able to post the code in the last days.